# How to add meta tag in index.html dynamically with data in angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, meta, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to share some content in facebook with title, image and description. For that I need to add meta tag dynamically in index.html. I tried every possible aspects but it's not working. The description, image are not showing after sharing in facebook.
 I searched many solutions but didn't work for me. Is there anyone to help me to get rid of this issue ?
thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SEO services given by Angular: **Title** and **Meta** from `@angular/platform-browser`.

First you will have to add some data to your routes, for example:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AboutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'About',
      metatags: {
        'og:description': `your description here`,
        'twitter:description': `your description`,
         keywords: `your keywords here`
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Then inside your method ngOnInit of your *app.component.ts* file, you will track the router events and for each NavigationEnd event (means a new page is reached) you will update your tags and title following the data specified in your routes :

```js
ngOnInit() {
    // Change page title on navigation  based on route data
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => {
          let route = this.activatedRoute;
          while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
          }
          return route;
        }),
        filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary'),
        mergeMap(route => route.data)
      )
      .subscribe(event => {
        const title = event['title'];
        if (title) {
          const _title = `${environment.appName} | `;
          this.titleService.setTitle(_title);
          this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'title', content: _title });
        }

        const tags = event['metatags'];
        if (tags) {
          for (const tag in tags) {
            this.metaService.updateTag({ property: tag, content: tags[tag] });
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

But for some data loaded dynamically, example a specified product, you can add this code inside you page component *product-details.component.ts* :

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.product$ = this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(
      switchMap((data) => this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
        // get the requested id in url to fetch the correct document
        switchMap((params) => this.productService.getProduct(params.get('id'))),
        tap((product: Product) => {
          const _title = `${environment.appName} | ${product.name}`;
          this.titleService.setTitle(_title);
          this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'title', content: _title });
          this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: product.description});
        }),
      )));

  }
```

Et voilà.

But you will probably need to add Angular Universal to your project because not all the search bots can analyse Single Page Application like Angular.

Comment: dynamic add update from any component by Meta service not working without angular universal